# Hive metastore with alluxio storage in parquet data type problem

Tags: hive, parquet, presto, alluxio

I am using prestodb with hive metastore for schema storage and alluxio cache as external storage for data. The storage format used in alluxio and hive schema is **PARQUET**. 
While retrieving timestamp field from presto using hive catalog. I get follow error.

The column utdate is declared as type **timestamp**, but the **Parquet** file declares the column as type **INT64**

Schema for dataset is

> create table test( utcdate timestamp ) WITH ( format='PARQUIET',
>   external_location='alluxio://path-toserver/directory-path-to-parquet'
>   )

This issue is produced after upgrade from prestodb **v0.221** to **v0.226** version.

Comment: I suggest you switch to PrestoSQL(https://prestosql.io/), which doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this while saving parquet to solve timestamp issue.

pyarrow.parquet.write_table(self.arrow_table, file_name, use_deprecated_int96_timestamps=True)

The presto and spark uses int96 timestamp value to store timestamp in nanoseconds. The default timestamp format for pyarrow table is int64, while presto consider int64 as bigint data type. If we use deprecated version of timestamp int96 in pyarrow we will get timestamp value in presto compatible format.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're asking about, so I assume the question is: how to read the data.

There is no switch or configuration change that you can apply to read your data while in .226 version. Thus you have currently two options:

- downgrade to Presto .221
- upgrade to [Presto 324](https://prestosql.io/download.html)

Comment: Presto .221 support int64 as timestamp, but presto .226 does not support int64 as timestamp. Rather .226 requires int96 as timestamp. Which is deprecated in pyarrow.

Comment: @ArsalanMudni did you check Presto 324? How does it play with pyarrow data?